# How to print something in command line/console in from Blender?

Tags: blender

I wrote some script which renders scenes and want see output on console I am using print but it not works what I should use to print something.

I run script with:

```
blender -b -P render.py
```

Want output such string from render.py:

```
print '#' * 80
```

It is little trivial question but print not works and not know how to progress development without debug messages.

Comment: Odd.. `print()` works for me.

Comment: `print "something"` only works in python2 - blender uses python3 which only allows `print ("something")`

Comment: I will test it add answer I will confirm.

Answer (score 2):

use the logging module to setup your custom logger.

you can setup a Console handler to log the content to the console or/and

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

setup a File handler if you want to log to a file:

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add the handler to the logger:
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

They can both have different log levels which you can set via script or environement variable:

```
log_level = level
if 'LOG_LEVEL' in os.environ:
    log_level = os.environ['LOG_LEVEL']
console_handler.setLevel(log_level)
file_handler.setLevel('INFO')
```

Read trough:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html